# How to use VHDL Entity in logisim evolution?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, logisim

I'm new in Logisim and VHDL. I'm trying to use VHDL entity-component but the output always is "x". Then I read a document ( [this link](https://www.microlab.ti.bfh.ch/wiki/huce:microlab:tools:linux-client:bfh-logisim?do=export_pdf&id=huce:microlab:tools:linux-client:bfh-logisim) ) that said Logisim requires ModelSim to use this feature. So I installed ModelSim ALTERA STARTER EDITION 10.1d - Custom Altera Version.

And I add the program path to Logisim's third-party software in the Questa Advanced Simulator path section.

```
C:\altera\13.0sp1\modelsim_ase\win32aloem
```

Then I create a VHDL entity in Logisim with code below.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity and_or_top is
    Port ( INA1, INA2 : in  STD_LOGIC;    -- AND gate input
           OA   : out STD_LOGIC);    -- AND gate output
end and_or_top;

architecture Behavioral of and_or_top is
begin
    OA <= INA1 and INA2;    -- 2 input AND gate
end Behavioral;
```

And I click VHDL simulation Enable in the simulate menu. Then the VHDL simulator log appears with errors.

```
Reading C:/altera/13.0sp1/modelsim_ase/tcl/vsim/pref.tcl 

# 10.1d

# do ../run.tcl 51429 
Run simulation environnment build...
# ** Warning: (vlib-34) Library already exists at "work".
# 
# Modifying modelsim.ini
# Model Technology ModelSim ALTERA vcom 10.1d Compiler 2012.11 Nov  2 2012
# -- Loading package STANDARD
# -- Loading package TEXTIO
# -- Loading package std_logic_1164
# -- Compiling entity and_or_top
# -- Compiling architecture Behavioral of and_or_top
# Model Technology ModelSim ALTERA vcom 10.1d Compiler 2012.11 Nov  2 2012
# -- Loading package STANDARD
# -- Loading package TEXTIO
# -- Loading package std_logic_1164
# -- Loading package NUMERIC_STD
# -- Compiling entity top_sim
# -- Compiling architecture comp of top_sim
# ** Error: (vsim-3296) Unknown option '-errorfile'.

# Use the -help option for complete vsim usage.
# Error in macro ./../run.tcl line 31
# ** Error: (vsim-3296) Unknown option '-errorfile'.

# Use the -help option for complete vsim usage.
# 
#     while executing
# "vsim top_sim"
```

VHDL entity output still is "x". If you know what I do wrong, please tell me. I'm using CS3410 Logisim evolution version 2.14.8.4. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Write another VHDL entity called "testbench" (with NO ports) and instantiate this one in it, with each port connected to a signal in the testbench. Add a process  to the testbench that drives the input signals with various values, waits for a few ns, and then (using "Assert" statements) checks the output port has the right value. Then make sure you simulate the testbench instead of the entity

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you for your reply. I'll try it.